# How can I specify a requirement only for Python 2 (ie not Python 3) in requirements.txt?

Tags: python, pip

I'm porting my project to support Python 3, it's got a dependency on SQLite, so I've got `pysqlite` in my requirements.txt

But the pysqlite module doesn't exist in Python 3 (it's built-in), how do I get my requirements.txt to work in both Python 2 and Python 3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pip (as of pip 6) supports [environment markers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426/#environment-markers).

To require pysqlite only on python < 3, use:

```
pysqlite ; python_version < '3'
```

https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirement-specifiers

Comment: Sorry, Just saw you put this and you are correct.